# Deploying web application in Tomcat 7 on Amazon EC2 on Ubuntu

Tags: java, spring, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, tomcat7

I'm trying to deploy my web application in tomcat 7 on external virtual machine Amazon EC2 on ubuntu and I always get an error. I'm running web application on my computer and it works.

Error:

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [com.test.registration.dao.UserDAOImpl] for bean with name 'userDAOImpl' defined in file [/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ServerApp/WEB-INF/classes/com/test/registration/dao/com.test.regist$
```

This is my main xml files:

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <!-- Описание корневого контейнера, разделяемого всеми сервлетами и фильтрами -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <!-- Создаёт контейнер Spring, разделяемый всеми сервлетами и фильтрами -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <!-- Базовый сервлет, обрабатывает все запросы к приложению -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>DownloadServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.test.servlets.DownloadServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>UploadServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.test.servlets.UploadServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>DownloadServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/downloadservlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>UploadServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/uploadservlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- Фильтр для перекодировки в utf8 -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>charsetFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>charsetFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>/login.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

root-context.xml

```
<?xml  version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

    <!-- Root Context: определяет ресурсы, доступные всему приложению, всем сервлетам -->

    <!-- Включаем опцию использования конфигурационных аннотаций (@Annotation-based configuration)-->
    <context:annotation-config />

    <!-- Определяем папки, в которых будем автоматически искать бины-компоненты (@Component, @Service)  -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.test.registration.dao">
        <context:include-filter expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"
            type="annotation" />
        </context:component-scan>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.test.registration.service">
        <context:include-filter expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"
            type="annotation" />
        </context:component-scan>

    <!-- Файл с настройками ресурсов для работы с данными (Data Access Resources) -->
    <import resource="data.xml" />

    <!-- Файл с настройками безопасности -->
    <import resource="security.xml" />

</beans>
```

data.xml

```
<?xml  version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

    <!-- Настраивает управление транзакциями с помощью аннотации @Transactional -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <!-- Менеджер транзакций -->
    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Настройки бина dataSource будем хранить в отдельном файле -->
    <bean id="propertyConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
        p:location="/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties" />

    <!-- Непосредственно бин dataSource -->
    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
        p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}" 
        p:url="${jdbc.databaseurl}"
        p:username="${jdbc.username}" 
        p:password="${jdbc.password}" />

    <!-- Настройки фабрики сессий Хибернейта -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="configLocation">
            <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
        </property>
        <property name="configurationClass">
            <value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</value>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.charSet">UTF-8</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

I deploy a simple programm HelloWorld and it works.
My spring version is 3.2.9RELEASE.

Comment: You have a reference to `userDAOImpl` somewhere in your code, but you aren't including that in your deployment. The reference is a Spring bean dependency I think, since it isn't referenced explicitly in your Spring XML configuration.

Comment: Thank you to your answer. I added string:  
<bean id="userDAOImpl" class="com.test.registration.dao.UserDAOImpl" /> 
 And it works!

Answer (score 0):

I added in data.xml string:

```
<bean id="userDAOImpl" class="com.test.registration.dao.UserDAOImpl" />
```

Also i deleted all russian comments! And now it works!